# Kaspa POW Chain Setup Issue: Miner Reports “Not Synced” Despite Genesis Block Presence

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, pow, proof-of-work

I’m currently learning how blockchain technology operates and decided to set up the Kaspa POW chain from scratch to gain practical experience. The GitHub repository I used for this purpose is [kaspa](https://github.com/kaspanet/kaspad).

Here are the steps I’ve completed so far:

```
1.  Successfully set up the node, wallet, and miner builds both locally and on a server.
2.  Set up the DNSSeeder, which appears to be functioning correctly as it returns the IP addresses of peers in the A record of a domain DNS query.
```

When I run the chain in a testnet environment, it successfully connects to the DNS seeder and establishes a connection with a remote node. However, I encounter an issue when starting the miner: it reports that Kaspa is “not synced,” even though a query to the network confirms the genesis block is successfully written to the network.

Question: How does the chain initiate at the very start? Could I be missing a step or configuration that’s causing this sync issue?

Additional details:

```
•   Despite the “not synced” status, I attempted to force start mining, and while mining began, it seems the nodes are not picking up the transactions at all.
•   This setup is intended for learning and experimental purposes, and any insights or advice on resolving the syncing issue would be greatly appreciated
```